# Why value in directive does not get updated - Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, directive

I just encounter a problem I have written a `directive` but its not getting update, I dont know why, in console it does change but in `directive` it does not.

Here is my directive

```
    mainControllers.directive('mallsproduct', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            productInfo: '=info',
            linkid: '=linkid'
        },
        templateUrl: 'directives/dashboard_product.html'
    };
});


Here is my `html`

      <div class="aa-properties-content-body mg-7" ng-controller="DashboardController as ctrl">
            <ul class="aa-properties-nav aa-list-view">
                <li style="border: 1px solid #ccc;margin-bottom: 25px;" ng-repeat="active_products in productInfo.items">
                    <article class="aa-properties-item mg-top-0-notimp">
                        <a class="aa-properties-item-img" href="#/product/{{active_products.id}}">
                            <img ng-if="active_products.photos[0].path" resize-image alt="img" class="" src="{{active_products.photos[0].path}}">
                            <img ng-if="!active_products.photos[0].path" resize-image class="" src="img/default_product.jpg"  alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="aa-properties-item-content">
                            <div class="aa-properties-about padding-0-notimp">
                                <h5><a href="#/product/{{active_products.id}}">{{active_products.name| limitTo : 10}}{{active_products.name.length > 10 ? '...' : ''}}</a></h5>
                                <p class="font-size-11-imp"><i class="fa fa-building-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{active_products.mall.name| limitTo : 10}}{{active_products.mall.name.length > 10 ? '...' : ''}}</p>
                                <p class="font-size-11-imp"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{active_products.mall.address| limitTo : 10}}{{active_products.mall.address.length > 10 ? '...' : ''}}</p>                      
                                <p class="font-size-11-imp"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{active_products.shop.telephone}}</p>                      
                                <p class="font-size-11-imp" ng-if="linkid == 3"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{active_products.views}}</p>              
                                <div class="modal-demo">
                                    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
                                        <div ng-include src="'partials/update_product.html'"></div> 
                                    </script>
                                    <div ng-controller="AddProductController">
                                        <button ng-click="view_product(active_products.id)"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>                             
                                        <button ng-click="del_product(active_products.id)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                        <button ng-if="linkid == 2" ng-init="status = 1" ng-click="reactivate_product(active_products.id, status)"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                    </div>          
                                    <div class="modal-parent">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="aa-title pad-top-30" ng-if="linkid == 1">
                <p>Global page count for active product  is {{global_pagecount}} and active product count from API is {{productInfo._meta.pageCount}}</p>
                <h3 ng-if="global_pagecount < productInfo._meta.pageCount"  class="text-align-center color-feroz cursor-pointer" ng-click="load_more(global_pagecount, linkid)">{{$root.translated_labels.dashboard.load_more}}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="aa-title pad-top-30" ng-if="linkid == 3">
                <p>Global page count for most viewed is {{global_pagecount_mostv}} and most viewed count from API is {{productInfo._meta.pageCount}}</p>
                <h3 ng-if="global_pagecount_mostv < productInfo._meta.pageCount"  class="text-align-center color-feroz cursor-pointer" ng-click="load_more(global_pagecount_mostv, linkid)">{{$root.translated_labels.dashboard.load_more}}</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am including directive in `dashboard` partial like this

```
 <div class="active tab-pane" ng-if="linkid === '1'">
                    <malls-product info="active_products" linkid="linkid"></malls-product>

                </div>

                <!--Active products list ends here -->

                <!-- Get Inactive Products -->

                <div class="active tab-pane" ng-if="linkid === '2'" >
                    <malls-product info="$root.inactive_products" linkid="linkid"></malls-product>
                </div>

                <!--Get Inactive products ends here -->

                <div class="active tab-pane" ng-if="linkid === '3'" >
                    <malls-product info="$root.mostviewed_products" linkid="linkid"></malls-product>
                </div>

                <!-- View Profile-->
```

and This is the `api` which does show the result in console.

```
$scope.global_pagecount = 1;

$scope.active_product = function () {
        $http.get($rootScope.baseurl + 'abc?&page=' + $scope.global_pagecount,
                {headers:
                            {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                'Authorization': $rootScope.keyword_auth_token, 'Accept-Language': $cookies.get('type')}
                })
                .success(function (data) {
                    //$scope.active_product_pageCount = data._meta.pageCount;

                    if ($scope.global_pagecount === 1) //I know for sure the first page of pagination is 1
                    {
                        $scope.active_products = data;
                    }
                    if ($scope.global_pagecount > 1) // If user click load more global count gets incremented and new results push in active_producst
                    {
                        /* for loading new results Pagination Applied */

                        for (var times = data.items.length - 1; times >= 0; times--) {
                            $scope.active_products.items.push(data.items[times]);
                        }
                    }
                    console.log($scope.active_products);

                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    //  console.log(data);
                });
    };
```

What is the issue, why it is not getting update, If I use `rootscope`then it works fine, obviously it has too, but not with `$scope`.

Note : when `scope.global_pagecount` value is equal to `2` i get new results but not in directive only in console. By default `scope.global_pagecount` has value equal to `1`.

Comment: What is `$scope.global_pagecount` ?

Comment: please see the api url , its page value , by default it is 1

Comment: Is that string or a number ?

Comment: $scope.global_pagecount = 1;

Answer (score 2):

You don't use your directive correctly. You define it as:

```
mainControllers.directive('mallsproduct'
```

Which means you should use it as:

```
<mallsproduct ..>
```

---

Or define your directive camelcased:

```
mainControllers.directive('mallsProduct'
```

Then you can use it as you do now:

```
<malls-product ..>
```

Comment: Applied your answer but still I am not getting the updated results.

Comment: please see my question and the last part NOTE too.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the **Isolated scope** doesn’t know anything about its parent scope. You just created a directive with an isolated scope.

To access any parent scope data, **we need to pass the scope data to our directive explicitly**. This is achieved by setting properties on the scope object in the DDO.

Another important thing is that, these properties also **MUST** be set as the attributes of the directive html element.